# Javascript Div class default tab

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use tablinks in my program using the w3school article

[how to js tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

CSS

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Below is the code to make one tab as "Active" one.

```js
   <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>

<script>
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

When i click on one tab i need to make it as default, so that next time when i open the page, the latest page should be the default.

I have few pages like sales, costs,expenses etc.
When the user makes an entry in costs, it will redirect to another jsp page and inserts the record to db and then redirect back to the home.jsp page where we have all these tabs. So when we redirect it should open the costs tab as default.

forgive me if my english is rude or badly formatted . english is not my mother tongue .

Thank you very much.. any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to store the tabs as they are clicked and then open those tabs when the page loads. Look at `window.localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: localStorage.setItem("divid", cityName);   document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem("divid")).click();
 not working unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Based on the article you linked, looks like css is governing which tab is showing.

This excerpt is from their example page later on.

```
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
```

So if you want to manage which tab and page is active, you will need to manage that active class using Javascript just like they are doing with the function on their example page.

Using their example, i was able to change the tab that displays by just calling:

```
    document.getElementById("Tokyo").style.display = "block";
    var tokyo = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks")
    tokyo[2].className += " active";
```

Comment: :( not able to understand